# Unable to import pymc3: AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'gof'

Tags: python, conda, theano, pymc3

I'm Trying to use pymc3 on MacOS (Mojave). I installed using anaconda and the installation is fine but when I try to import it I get `AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'gof'.`

There seems to be some discussion on it here (where it says that I need to install OS X 10.9 SDK) https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/6645. I'm not sure how to do that (and the instruction is not clear to me). I also don't know if it's a legit thing to do and whether it will cause some problems down the road.

I mostly just want to get pymc3 since it seems to be the standard package to use for Bayesian Inference (e.g. MCMC) in python. Also happy to use another package but this one seems to be the best/easiest(?). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you really want this troubleshot properly, you should also include the output of `conda info` and `conda list` for the env you are using.

Comment: Happy to do that but they're really long. Is there anything specific that I should look for in the output of those commands?

Comment: The issue you linked seems to place the blame on having `clang` in the Conda env

Comment: When I run conda list I get 4 items related to clang (The link was the best that I could find related to my issue but I'm not sure if the solution is what I need for my issue): clang    4.0.1   1  
clang_osx-64              4.0.1               h1ce6c1d_11  
clangxx                   4.0.1                         1  
clangxx_osx-64            4.0.1               h22b1bf0_11

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to get up and running, and which should avoid these issues, is to create a new Conda environment for it, with PyMC3 as the only requirement:

```
conda create --name your_env pymc3
```

I generally recommend creating new Conda envs for different purpose libraries you plan to use. This helps minimize conflicts and keeps your **base** env stable.

Comment: I have a lot of info of work in my current environment that I would like to use as inputs into it (so creating a new environment will be a lot of double doing).

Comment: @No0b what do you mean by "*info of work*"? The only things in an env are packages, not data.